# Wordpress Query_Posts Combine

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the Wordpress theme called Clipper with Flatter as the child theme.

The theme uses query_output to output results in the homepage. My intention is to sort by custom fields, 'clr_up_vote'. However, this caused the outputs to be reduced to only posts with 'clr_up_vote' data and hid the rest.

I initially set out to fix by having two queries in index.php,

```
$ordered_posts =   query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE
    , 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    , 'paged' => $page
    , 'posts_per_page' => 10
    , 'offset' => $offset
    ,'meta_key' => 'clpr_votes_up',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
         'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'clpr_votes_up',
        'meta-value' => $value,
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
                    'key' => 'clpr_votes_down',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
    )


));
get_template_part('loop', 'coupon');
```

And,

```
$unordered_posts =   query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE
    , 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0
    , 'paged' => $page 
    , 'posts_per_page' => 10-count($ordered_posts)
    , 'offset' => $offset
    , 'post__not_in' => $post_ids
));

get_template_part('loop', 'coupon');
```

But now the pagination doesn't seem to work. I tried to use WP_Query but the theme will only accept query_posts().

Any suggestions will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove meta query from query posts. Just orderby should be set to meta value and meta key should be set to the clpr_votes_up.

```
$ordered_posts =   query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE
    , 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    , 'paged' => $page
    , 'posts_per_page' => 10
    , 'offset' => $offset
    ,'meta_key' => 'clpr_votes_up',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

And if you want all the posts then remove posts_per_page from the query.